# yum install, select and link a specific version of a software

Tags: yum

Suppose I want to install python2.7 with `yum`, and do

```
sudo yum install python27
```

This will install a `python2.7` in the `/usr/bin` directory. However, the symbolic link `/usr/bin/python` still points to `python2.6`.

Is there a `yum` command that can manage this symbolic link rather than doing it manually? I know the `port select` in MacPorts does so, and am looking for a counterpart in `yum`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What version of RedHat/CentOS is this on? Where did that `python2.7` package come from? (Do you mean `python27` from the python27 SCL?) RedHat/CentOS doesn't generally do this sort of dual-version packaging as far as I'm aware (the SCLs are a recent exception and make sure not to collide with the default version).

Comment: I'm using Amazon Linux AMI on EC2, and am very new to it (as well as the whole `yum` package system). Yes, I meant `yum install python27`, which is listed as `python27-2.7.8-6.74.amzn1.x86_64`. This will install `python27` and `python2.7` on my `/usr/bin/` folder. Thanks.

Comment: Hm... I don't know where that package is coming from exactly (though it is probably something like the SCL).

Comment: Do you have a `python` (or something) file in `/etc/alternatives`?

Comment: Nope. There are all sorts of symbolic links like `c++`, `gfortran`, etc., but not something related to `python`. What does those links do? Shall I add one for `python`?

Comment: No. If there isn't one there then I don't believe the system is set up to support that for python. Which is the assumption my answer is based on. tl;dr You don't want to do what you are asking about because you will probably break things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the distribution has been set up to handle this sort of thing (the way debian and some others are) you **do not** want to be changing the default value of something like `/usr/bin/python` because you will break anything the distribution packages which depends on the default python being the version of python in the default `python` package.

Things built against the `python27` package almost certainly use `/usr/bin/python2.7` when they need to run python scripts and/or on their shebang lines. Things packaged by the default system almost certainly just use `/usr/bin/python` assuming that is the default system python version.